# Cortar texto (String) en C#

Tags: c#

Necesito acortar un pedazo de texto (String) en C# y no encuentro forma.

(Cortar un pedazo y mostrarlo con `Console.WriteLine()` )

Texto ejemplo: 123456
Texto resultado: 123

¡Gracias por la ayuda de antemano!

Answer (score 0):

```
string number= "123456";    

string getnumer= number.Substring(0, 2);    
Console.WriteLine(getnumer);
```

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar substring que lo que hace es retornar una subcadena, dicho método recibe 2 parámetros, la posicion en la que quieres comenzar y la ultima posición del texto que quieres tomar

```
var text = "123456";
Console.WriteLine(text.Substring(0, 3));
// resutado en consola : 123
```

Dale una revisada a [esto](https://www.dotnetperls.com/substring)